# Change the step auto_increment fields increment by

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

How do I change the amount `auto_increment` fields in MySQL increment by from the default (1) to n?

Comment: Do you want to change the next value used, or the step being used between values (e.g. step value of 2, use 1, 3, 5, 7 etc)?

Comment: sorry if the question is ambiguous yes correct i want the auto_increment should be performed as stated by you (like the identity(1,3) in sql server which increase the next value by 3)

Comment: @sansknwoledge - I've edited the question to hopefully make it ask what you meant!

Answer (score 9):

If you want to change autoincrement step from 1 to N then there is a solution.
It could be done on MySQL server side:
look for '--auto-increment-increment' startup option or use following command `SET @@auto_increment_increment=2;`, but be warned that this is a server wide change (all tables will increment by 2).

Unortodox solutions could that could be considered:

1. Launch two MySQL servers on same machine, with different ports (one with `auto_increment_increment=1` other with `auto_increment_increment=2`)
2. Use some serverside magic (PHP, ASP ,???) combined with turning off tables `auto_increment` to manually calculate (simple peek at last id and +=2 would be ok) and provide id in `INSERT` query.

[Some official MySQL FAQ](http://aqua.sun.ddns.vc/free/docs/mysql5.1/faqs.html)

Comment: hi, i checked the faq i am little bit confused [you can set each server to generate auto-increment values that don't conflict with other servers. The --auto-increment-increment value should be greater than the number of servers (from that page)] could any body explain this?

Comment: the idea is this: servers={db1,db2,db3}; db01:{--auto-increment-offset=0;--auto-increment-increment=3};db02:{--auto-increment-offset=1;--auto-increment-increment=3};db03:{--auto-increment-offset=2;--auto-increment-increment=3};

so, db1 only generates IDs where (n % 3) == 0, for db2 (n % 3) == 1, for db3 (n % 3) == 2; i.e. db1:"3,6,9,..." db2:"1,4,7,..." db3:"2,5,8" -> no id conflict

Comment: @Piskvor thanks for the clarification, but if i am having more than one table in my db all with autogenerate columns and i want only one table to increment in steps of say 2 and rest follow 3 what should i do?

Comment: Is there any way to make this increment by step for only a single table.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it using [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = n;
```

Or if you want to do set it from start:

```
CREATE TABLE table (...) AUTO_INCREMENT = n;
```

Comment: I don't *think* that does what he wants (it answers the question he asks in the body of his question, but not the question in the title). The question is definitely ambiguous though.

Comment: Yep, this doesn't do what he's trying to do (I've now edited the question to hopefully make it clearer).

Answer (score -3):

You can also use 
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name INCREMENT BY N where N is the new incremnent value.

Answer (score -4):

```
alter table <table name>  auto_increment=n
```

where n is the number you want to start

Comment: This doesn't adjust the step it adjusts the start value.

Comment: This is only the start value