# change AUTO_INCREMENT attribute step by n value for particular table

Tags: mysql, sql

[Change the step auto_increment fields increment by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by)

The above link describes how to change the step value of AUTO_INCREMENT in mysql. This will affect all tables.

Is this behavior is specific to mysql? Can someone suggest a DBMS that allows for the step value to be set per table?

Comment: I am just curious. Why would you want the auto_increment to step by n value? it is mostly intended for primary keys so that you do not have to set it or keep track of the latest (or hash of all values) yourself... If you have a specific field you want to step, why don't you do it by a program or SQL statement?

Comment: @Saher, to ensure two MySQL instances in a cluster don't generate the same id values.

Comment: auto increment is per table.... if you have 10 tables, each of them will have their own auto increment

Comment: @BillKarwin if you're using auto-increment in a cluster setup, you're really begging for trouble. This is strongly discouraged.

Comment: @Romain, I agree it's risky if done improperly, but I have consulted for dozens of MySQL sites and I see it used successfully a lot.  It's a topic for another thread though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, `AUTO_INCREMENT` as a keyword is specific to MySQL, because other RDBMS brands implement different features to generate artificial unique id values.  MySQL and SQLite are the only widely-used RDBMS that *don't* allow per-table incrementation options.

### Microsoft SQL Server

SQL Server declares a column with an [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) option, and the IDENTITY keyword can take arguments for the initial value and the increment, so you can vary this per table.

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
 id int IDENTITY(1,2),
 fname varchar (20),
 minit char(1),
 lname varchar(30)
)
```

### Oracle

Oracle uses a [SEQUENCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm) object and you call NEXTVAL() to get new values for primary keys.  You can use a single sequence for multiple tables, or a specific sequence for a specific table, or any combination.  You just name the sequence explicitly every time you INSERT.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10; 

INSERT INTO employee (id) VALUES (s.NEXTVAL);
```

### PostgreSQL

PostgreSQL has [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) objects with the same options, and you can declare which sequence a table uses for automatic generation of values.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE s START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 10; 

CREATE TABLE employee (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('s')
);
```

You can also declare [SERIAL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html) as a shorthand, and this implicitly creates a sequence for the column.  I haven't tested it, but I suppose you could ALTER SEQUENCE on the sequence it creates, to change its incrementation step.

### IBM DB2

DB2 has sequence objects too.  DB2 also can declare columns to [auto-generate identity](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0407zhang/index.html) values.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
  SERIALNUMBER  BIGINT NOT NULL 
        GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
        (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
  FIRSTNAME CHAR(64),
  LASTNAME  CHAR(64),
  SALARY        DECIMAL(10, 2),
  PRIMARY KEY (SERIALNUMBER)
);
```

Or:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EMPSERIAL
 AS BIGINT
 START WITH 1
 INCREMENT BY 10;
```

### SQLite

SQlite doesn't seem to have a means to change its [auto-increment](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) increment either globally or per-table; it increments by 1 until it reaches maxint, then it tries a few random values, then gives up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if other database systems can change the step value of AUTO_INCREMENT? If so, yes, you can do this in SQL Server. I suspect most RDBS support this, but I know it's supported in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server - IDENTITY

```
IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Oracle - SEQUENCE

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Test_Sequence
INCREMENT BY 1
START WITH 1;

INSERT INTO Test (ID, Val)
VALUES (Test_Sequence.NEXTVAL, 1);
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm