# MySQL primary keys are auto incrementing odd numbers only - Why?

Tags: mysql

I developed a backend on a local MySQL server and everything was normal.
After I moved it to the production server all of my primary keys in the database are auto incrementing to odd numbers only (it could also be that it is auto incrementing by 2) - So 1,3,5,7,9 ...

I know it is possible to change the auto increment amount, but I didn't do that. So how could I check to see if that was set somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the step auto\_increment fields increment by](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's likely that the `auto_increment_increment` was changed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment

You can check like this:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| auto_increment_increment | 10    |
| auto_increment_offset    | 1     |
+--------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Nailed it! auto_increment_increment: 2 ... Any reason a system admin would have set that as a default?

Comment: If you're running a master-master replication setup, this will prevent you from having primary key conflicts. One server does even id's, the other does odd id's.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to an `INSERT` statement being sent twice, but with an `IGNORE` thus causing only odd numbers.

Comment: It is working well on OP's test server with the same code, I'd rather bet on dual-master replication setup.

Comment: It's happening on all the tables. I did (early on) catch this issue though. Never knew that ignore still incremented the primary key

Comment: This is quite an old issue but i just happen to face the same issue. After DB migration it is happening to all tables. what could be the potential fix for this.