# mysql issue with auto-increment

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am facing a problem with mysql auto-increment , actually it is not creating any problem.
I am just confused why mysql auto-increment field getting even data.
Evertytime a new entry its creating like this
`2,4,6,8,10.......`
insteed of `1,2,3,4,5,6.......`

Have you know about this or facing situation like this.

Comment: are you using InnoDB? If so you might see gaps due to roll backs or bulk inserts: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html

Comment: Has [`auto_increment_increment`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment) been set to 2?

Comment: @eggyal how we will set

Comment: "How we will set" is incomplete sentence, mind finishing it so there's  a meaning to it?

Comment: Check this Post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686327/change-the-step-auto-increment-fields-increment-by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%';`

use it to check autoincrement and set it to proper values with

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment=1;
```

It will set auto increment to 1

Answer (score 0):

To show auto_increment and its offset values, should use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'auto_inc%'`

For resetting `AUTO_INCREMENT` values, use :

```
SET @@auto_increment_increment = 1;
SET @@auto_increment_offset = 1;
```

To set globally you should add `@@GLOBAL` :

```
SET @@GLOBAL.auto_increment_offset = 1;
SET @@GLOBAL.auto_increment_increment = 1;
```